# How can you fight with two weapons?

Tags: traveller

I'm running Mongoose Traveller and one of my players wants to have their PC dual-wield pistols. I can't find any rules for two-weapon fighting in the core book or Central Supply Catalog. The same question goes for two melee weapons, like swords and axes. How should I rule this?

Comment: I don't know if there's any official rule for it, but consider this thread:

http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?691317-Mongoose-Traveller-Rules-Questions

Basically, here's what it suggests:

Add a -2 or -4 DM penalty (depending on how lenient you are), and also increase the recoil as a result of trying to use weapons in one hand.

Comment: Please do not answer in comments.

Comment: I will return it for a day, and then delete it again. @KyleWilley please turn this into a real answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! If @KyleWilley will not return, than I should anwser to my question myself (for other players and googlers).

Comment: Feel free to answer it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to rule two weapon fighting is treating it like "Multiple Actions" as stated on the p.50 of Core Rulebook. According this rule character will suffer -2 DM to all skill checks.
Also it's good to increase recoil of the weapons by 1 as a result of trying to use each weapon in one hand and for the difficulty of keeping both guns on target.

And according for what I know about fighting with two swords this rules are applied well for them too.

The answer was written in accordance to this thread: http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?691317-Mongoose-Traveller-Rules-Questions

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to suggest allowing them to fire a secondary weapon at the same target using their minor action, or maybe "charging" them a Reaction (-2 init, -1 skill checks until next round). Also, no aiming, since it's physically impossible to aim down both weapons without some electronic assistance.

As Kyle suggested, I'd do +1 Recoil. And maybe charge them for the Reaction BEFORE they fire, so they take the penalty then.

For melee weapons, I'd just allow the character to choose which weapon to attack with and which to parry with each round. Or charge them -1 for "dual weapons", but allow them to parry without the usual penalties. Which means that dual-wielders will be better at defending themselves, but not necessarily better on the attack.

Comment: There is no logic to treat this as reaction. Right answer is making multiple actions (-2 DM to all skill checks) and increased recoil for using each weapon in one hand.

I like the answer about melee weapons, I will think in this way, but I dont know about two-weapon fighting much to rule this as parring only.

Comment: I apologize for my poor phrasing - I didn't intend that the secondary attack should BE a reaction, just that it would provide similar penalties as a reaction.

I agree that multiple action penalties are the right answer though. I had momentarily forgotten about those.